# Converting multiple files into HTML (from Markdown)?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I'm currently working on a small project in which I want to convert couple (or more) Markdown files into HTML and then append them to the main document. I want all this to take place client-side. I have chose couple of plugins such as [Showdown](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown) (Markdown to HTML converter), jQuery (overall DOM manipulation), and Underscore (for simple templating if necessary). I'm stuck where I can't seem to convert a file into HTML (into a string which has HTML in it).

Converting Markdown into HTML is simple enough:

```
var converter = new Showdown.converter();
converter.makeHtml('#hello markdown!');
```

I'm not sure how to fetch (download) a file into the code (string?).

How do I fetch a file from a URL (that URL is a Markdown file), pass it through Showdown and then get a HTML string? *I'm only using JavaScript by the way.*

Comment: is this Showdown some port of the `Markdown Pagedown` plugin?

Comment: I think it was ported from a Perl Markdown implementation by John Fraser. You should check out the [README](https://github.com/coreyti/showdown#showdown-).

Comment: it isn't bad... but I prefer the one I mentioned... Markdown Pagedown :) http://goo.gl/XI3L0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an external file and parse it to a string with ajax.  The jQuery way is cleaner, but a vanilla JS version might look something like this:

```
var mdFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
mdFile.open("GET", "http://mypath/myFile.md", true);
mdFile.onreadystatechange = function(){
 // Makes sure the document exists and is ready to parse.
 if (mdFile.readyState === 4 && mdFile.status === 200)   
 {
    var mdText = mdFile.responseText; 
    var converter = new showdown.Converter();
    converter.makeHtml(mdText);
    //Do whatever you want to do with the HTML text
 }
}
```

jQuery Method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "info.md",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(mdText){
    //where text will be the text returned by the ajax call
    var converter = new showdown.Converter();
    var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(mdText);
    $(".outputDiv").append(htmlText); //append this to a div with class outputDiv
  }
});
```

Note: This assumes the files you want to parse are on your own server.  If the files are on the client (IE user files) you'll need to take a different approach

#### Update

The above methods will work if the files you want are on the same server as you.  If they are NOT then you will have to look into CORS if you control the remote server, and a server side solution if you do not.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) provides some relevant background on cross-domain requests.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is downloaded when I want to open [this](https://raw.github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/README.md) URL. Could you please show how to use the jQuery Ajax method?

Comment: Thanks, the jQuery one works a little better but it seems like the file is not fetched. When I look at my Network tab I see "Status" Failed for the file I'm trying to get. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zapluSm.png). I also get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://rafalchmiel.com/post_1.md. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. `.

Comment: ok, I didn't realize you were making this request to a different domain than the one you're currently on.  You're going to need to use CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the HTML string, you can append to the whatever DOM element you wish, by simply calling:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
myElement.innerHTML += markdownHTML;
```

...where markdownHTML is the html gotten back from makeHTML.